Prove this function is right continuous
Let $f(x)$ be defined as :
$\sin(x) \int_{x}^{1}{\frac{1}{t\cos(t)}}dt$ if  $x\gt 0$ ; $0$ if $x=0$
I want to show that this function is right continuous, that is
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} $ $\sin(x) \int_{x}^{1}{\frac{1}{t\cos(t)}}dt$$ =0$
I  think a good idea would be to show that the improper integral is convergent, and therefore the integral has a value A. Then, since $\lim_{x \to 0^{+ }} |\sin(x) =0$, we are done. Is this a good idea, or there is an easier path? I would appreciate some comments on this.
Thanks.

What function is $sen(x)$?

I think that’s $\sin(x)$ in English

@Asigan sin(x). I edited.

You can not expect $\int_{x}^{1}{\frac{1}{t\cos(t)}}dt$ converges as $x\to 0+$ since $\frac{1}{t\cos t}\sim \frac 1t$ as $t\to 0+$.

For $t\in(0,1)$ we have $$\cos(1)\leq\cos(t)\leq 1$$ so $$\dfrac{1}{t}\leq\dfrac{1}{t\cos(t)}\leq \dfrac{1}{\cos(1)}\dfrac{1}{t}$$
and consequently $$-\ln(x)=\displaystyle\int_{x}^{1} \dfrac{1}{t} dt\leq\displaystyle\int_{x}^{1}\dfrac{1}{t\cos(t)}dt\leq \displaystyle\int_{x}^{1} \dfrac{1}{\cos(1)}\dfrac{1}{t}dt=-\dfrac{1}{\cos(1)}\ln(x) $$
Using that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}=1, \quad\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln(x)=0$$
and the squeeze theorem we immediately find $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(\sin(x) \displaystyle\int_{x}^{1}\dfrac{1}{t\cos(t)}dt\right)=0,$$
as desired.

$$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \sin x\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t\cos t}{\rm d}t =\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t\cos t}{\rm d}t}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}.$$
Since $\frac{1}{\sin x}\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0+$,
we can use L Hospital's rule once we checked
$$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\left(\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t\cos t}{\rm d}t\right)'} {\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)' }  $$
indded exists.
In fact $$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\left(\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t\cos t}{\rm d}t\right)'} {\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)' }= \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{-\frac 1{x\cos x}}{-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}} =0. $$
Therefore we justified the use of L Hospital's rule and yield
$$ \lim_{x\to 0+} \sin x\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t\cos t}{\rm d}t =0  .$$
